# How do I reconstruct the forest of syntax trees from the Earley vector?

Tags: context-free, dynamic-programming, parsers, ambiguity, syntax-trees

Using the Earley vector as a recognizer is quite straightforward: when the end of the string is reached, you just have to check for a completed axiomatic production started at position 0. If you have at least one, then the string is accepted.

Using the Earley vector to reconstruct the parsing tree(s) is less obvious. Actually, I cannot figure out how an algorithmic procedure would work, moreover the only references I found were either vague or super-technical. Could anybody shed some light on it?

Comment: It would help if you listed the references you found, and which you thought were vague, and which you thought were overly technical.  Otherwise the answer is likely to be a pointer to the references you already found.

Comment: It may be that what you call vector is not what Earley calls vector in
his original paper. Or it may be that it does not play exactly the
same role. Authors do introduce variations in algorithms. There is no
way to know *since you do not give any reference to the documents you
have been using* ... and we may not have access to them anyway. What
may help is to be more explicit about definitions. When answering, I
just assumed you used the same definitions as Earley's.

Comment: @babou, what I called _"Earley vector"_ is the tabular representation of the data structure built by the parser. It was the term used by my Formal Languages professor while referring to it. It should be noted that my primary language is not English, so this might be just a bad attempt at translating the terminology. The technical reference I mentioned is Earley's paper itself. I approached it, but it was a little intimidating for a true beginner like me.

Comment: You may want to check whether "Earley vector" is used by your
professor to mean the same structure as what Earley calls "vector" in
his paper. May be useful for communicating. For the rest, as you can
see, you have to keep extra information to be able to recover parse
trees, but Earley does not really go into details. There are now other
algorithms and I am afraid the complexities of Earley's algorithm hide
somewhat the key ideas of this type of techniques. Good luck.

Comment: Was my explanation helpful, or do you need a more detailed description of the technical part?

Comment: @babou unfortunately, I am in a period of tight deadlines and I am currently unable to allocate enough time to critically read your writeup and comment. I will go through it as soon as possible. Thank you so much for your availability :)

Comment: No hurry, but I would like to know whether the explanation was
adequate, or why it does not get across.

Comment: @babou it was adequate, indeed. With a lot of readings (including your nice writeup) and experiments, eventually all pieces clicked together. Beg you pardon for the somewhat long time it took me to review your answer.

Comment: No problem with time. I sometimes take quite long too, on complex issues, before ultimately getting to it. I hope your exams went well.

Comment: [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) is an open source implementation of an Earley parser with full parse forest support. It has a Perl front end and C back end. It might be of use for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using terminology and notations from [Earley's paper](http://ccl.pku.edu.cn/alcourse/nlp/LectureNotes/An_Efficient_Context_Free_Parsing_Algorithm%20%28Earley%20Algorithm%29.pdf). It is possible that the description you read is different.

It seems frequent that general CF parsing algorithms are first
presented in the form of a recognizer, and then the information
management needed to actually build parse trees and parse forests is
sort of added as an afterthought. One reason may be that keeping the
information needed to construct the shared forest require cubic space
$O(n^3)$ where $n$ is the length of the input string being parsed, but
the space requirement is only square $O(n^2)$ for recognition, when this information is
not preserved. The reason for this space complexity increase is quite
simple: the parse forest size can be cubic.

The worst case time complexity is $O(n^3)$, as is well known.

The best reference for Earley's algorithm is of course [Earley's paper](http://ccl.pku.edu.cn/alcourse/nlp/LectureNotes/An_Efficient_Context_Free_Parsing_Algorithm%20%28Earley%20Algorithm%29.pdf),
but it is not very explicit about building the parse forest. This can
actually be a messy business, much more so than the fast talk of
section 7 page 101 will let appear. To be true, Earley does not talk
of parse forest, or of forest, but of "*a factored representation of
all possible parse trees*". And there is a good reason for that: if he
tried to produce a forest according to his grammar, his space (hence
time) complexity bound would climb to $O(n^{s+1})$ where $s$ is the
size of the longest rule right-hand-side. This is why other algorithms
use grammars in binary form (not necessarily Chomsky Normal Form (CNF)).

Actually, *Earley uses binary form implicitly*, because that is
necessary for the cubic time complexity. This is one of the major
roles of the rule dot in states. But this implicit binary form
produces parses and forests according to the binarized grammar, not
to the original one, which, I fear, is a major source of obscurity. This is detailed further below.

One good way to understand how the forest is obtained is probably to
look at it in a simpler case, [the CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm). It is also often
described as a recognizer, and the [parser aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm#Generating_a_parse_tree) is added at the end.
You can look at the description in wikipedia. *The information needed
to build the forest is what they store in the table of "backpointers".*
Backpointers are essentially pointers to substrings (an associated
symbol) that form the constituents of a string according to some
rule. They give all possible ways of parsing a substring. Recall that
CYK uses binary form, usually CNF, so that things are simpler. The CYK
parser has fundamentally the same dynamic programming structure as
Earley, but is much simpler. So understanding it well can be a
significant help.

Going back to Earley's algorithm, I do not believe you need Earley
vector to decide acceptance or to build parse trees and forests.  What
Earley calls vector in his paper appears only in page 97, in third
paragraph of implementation. It is only a device to speed up the
search of states pointing back at some given string position k, in
order to get a better complexity. But all the information is in the
state sets, implemented as lists of states. However, this information
is not sufficient to build the forest of parse trees, because the
algorithm does not keep track of the way(s) a state may be
obtain. Indeed, the vector is even used to efficiently discard a state
already found, independently of how it was found.

In section 7 of Earley's article, he explains that in order to "make
the recognizer into a parser", i.e. to be able to recover parse trees,
it is necessary to keep track of the way completions are done.

> Each time we perform the completer operation adding a state
>     $E\rightarrow \alpha D.\beta \; g$ (ignoring lookahead) we construct a pointer from the instance of $D$ in
>   that state to the state $D\rightarrow \gamma. \; f$ which caused us to do the
>   operation. This indicates that $D$ was parsed as $\gamma$. In case
>   D is ambiguous there will be a set of pointers from it,
>   one for each completer operation which caused $E\rightarrow \alpha
> D.\beta \; g$ to be added to the particular state set. Each symbol in
>   $\gamma$ will also have pointers from it (unless it is terminal),
>   and so on, thus representing the derivation tree for $D$.

Note that in this text, $f$ and $g$ are indices in the parsed string,
pointing where the recognition of the rule left-hand side started (as
the right-hand side symbol had been predicted. So $f$ is the string
index where the recognition of $D\rightarrow \gamma$ started, and it
ended at index $g$. These "completion pointers" are the Earley
equivalent of the backpointers described (not too well in
wikipedia) for the parser version of CYK.

From such a pointer (as described in the quote) we know that the $D$
in the rule instance $E\rightarrow \alpha D.\beta \; g$ can itself be
developped into a tree (or forest) that parses the input string $w$ from
index $f+1$ to index $g$, which we note $w_{f+1:g}$. The nodes immediately below $D$ are given by
the rule $D\rightarrow \gamma$. By looking for the completion that lead
to $D\rightarrow \gamma. \; f$ we can then find other such pointers
that tell how the last symbol of $D$ was obtained, and hence more
information on the possible parse trees. Also by looking at the
completion that recognized the symbol before last in an earleir state
sets, you find how it was obtained, and so on.

Assuming you kept all the needed pointers as indicated in the paper,
you can get all the shared tree representations starting from the last
symbol recognized by the parser, which is of course the initial symbol
of the grammar.

But I also skipped **the messy part**. Suppose you have a rule
$U\rightarrow XYZ$, which I choose with a right hand side longer than
2 symbols, and another rule $W\rightarrow UV$, for an ambiguous
grammar.

It may well happen that the parser will parse $w_{f+1:g}$ into $X$,
$w_{g+1:h}$ into $Y$ and both $w_{h+1:i}$ and $w_{h+1:j}$ into
$Z$. So, with the rule $U\rightarrow XYZ$, Both $w_{f+1:i}$ and
$w_{f+1:j}$ parse into $U$.

Then it may also be that both $w_{i+1:k}$ and $w_{j+1:k}$ both
parse into $V$. Then, with the rule $W\rightarrow UV$, the string
$w_{f+1:k}$ parse into $W$ in two different way, which correspond to
an ambiguity of the grammar.

Of course, to avoid repeating computations, Earley's algorithm will
attempt to share as much as possible of the two parsing computations.
What it will actually share is obviously the recognition (and parsing)
of $w_{f+1:g}$ and $w_{g+1:h}$ into $X$ and $Y$. But it will actually
do a bit more: it will also share the beginning of the two distinct
parses that recognize $U$ with the rule $U\rightarrow XYZ$. What I
mean is that the state $U\rightarrow XY.Z \; f$ will be found only
once (with respect to what I am describing), in state set $S_h$. It
will be a common part of the two parses. Of course, things will
temprarily diverge while parsing the $Z$ since they correspond to
distict substrings, until they converge again when everything parses
into W, when the state $W\rightarrow UV. \; f$ is produced twice in
state set $S_k$.

So the forest of syntax trees can be a very strange one, with kind of
siamese twin subtrees that may share the first two edges of some node, but
not the third edge. In other words, it may be a very awkward
structure. This may explain why Earley calls it "*a factored representation of
all possible parse trees*", without being more specific.

Any attenpt to surgically separate the siamese twins, without changing
the grammar will result in increased complexity. The right way to do it
is to binarize the grammar.

I hope this will help you. Let me know.  But I do insist that a good
understanding of CYK parsing can help. There are other algorithms, simpler than Earley's, that can parse all CF languages efficiently.

You may find more general info on this parse forest issue in two other answers I gave: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374#18006 and https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619#6120. But they do not go into specific details of Earley's algorithm.

Comment: As well as CYK parsing, it's also worth looking into GLR parsing.

Comment: @Pseudonym Knowing and understanding various forms of general CF
parsing certainly does not hurt, and I suggest as much with the two
references at the answer end. However, my choice of CYK was not due to
chance. It shares with Earley's algorithm the property of being
interpretative, using the grammar directly, rather than using tables
produced by compiling of the grammar into a Push-Down Automaton (as in
GLR, GLL, GPrec). Hence the relation between the recognition process
and the tree/forest generation is more clearly visible. CKY is also
the simplest algorithm, with one exception.